# Linker error for core.sys.windows.winuser imports when compiling as 64 bit

Tags: windows, winapi, d, user32, dmd

I'm getting a linker error when compiling with DMD `-m64` that I don't get as 32 bit.

I'm importing `ShowWindow` from `core.sys.windows.winuser`, and I get the following:

```
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\lld-link.exe: warning: main.obj: undefined symbol: ShowWindow
error: link failed
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

My compiler command is `dmd main.d -m64 -i -O -release -inline -boundscheck=off`.

I don't think the source code would make a difference other than to say that I'm calling `ShowWindow`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try adding `pragma(lib, "user32");` to your main.d. and if that doesn't work... I don't know the command line flag for lld, but if the pragma doesn't work, maybe adding `-L-luser32` will do it (to your dmd command line btw) and let me know if it works. (also random comment, but `-boundcheck=off` is almost always a bad, bad idea for program correctness)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thanks Adam. I did that, but I keep getting other errors. Missing files, etc. Is there online information for setting up a 64 bit dev environment? I keep making mistakes and I know someone has to have figured it out before.

Comment: I just used the installer exe and let it do the thing automatically, including downloading visual studio for 64 bit...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adam from the comments (he's useful everywhere honestly) the solution was to add `pragma(lib, "user32")`.

But as I ran into more problems with `libcurl` after that, I eventually just switched to using `ldc2`, the LLVM based D compiler. It is much better in my opinion, it cut down on a lot of the errors relating to "missing stuff".

I seems to work seamlessly with the standalone Visual Studio Build Tools, unlike DMD which did not immediately pick up on my environment settings. It might have, if I let the installer manage the VS Build Tools installation, bit I didn't want that big bloated mess of packages that comes along with a full install of Visual Studio.

Comment: so dmd doesn't pick up the settings, it needs to be told. the installer does it, but if doing your own thing it is an adjustment to dmd.conf (though I don't know exactly what)... BTW you can also accept your own answer if it indeed solves the problem you described originally.

Comment: @AdamDRuppe I know I can accept my own answer, but it's just not very good. I didn't know about the configuration file, but LLVM seems nicer anyways.